# Quotient maps are closed under direct sum?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

This result seems wrong but I can't find where went wrong in this argument.

> Let $q:X \rightarrow Y$ be a quotient map of top spaces. $g:A \rightarrow Y$ a continuous map. Then I claim the map 
>   $(q,g):X \oplus A \rightarrow Y$ 
>   is a quotient map.

---

*(Flawed?) Proof:* We use the [universal property of quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Properties).  $(q,g)$ is surjective as $q$ is. $(q,g)$ is quotient if and only if for any map $h:Y \rightarrow Z$, $h(q,g)$ is continuous if and only if $h$ is. One direction follows by continuity of $(q,g)$.

Suppose $h(q,g)$ is continuous. Then $hq:X \rightarrow Z$ is continuous. But by universal property with respect to $q:X \rightarrow Y$, $h$ is continuous. So $(q,g)$ is indeed a quotient map.

Comment: I think it is correct (cannot find a flaw). Also surjectivity has been take care of (you did not mention that as condition for being a quotient map). If $h\circ(q,g)$ is continuous then so is $h\circ q=h\circ(q,g)\circ i_1$ where $i_1:X\to X\oplus A$ denotes the injection. Then $h$ continuous since $q$ is a quotient map.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I forgot to mention surjectivity, but if $q$ is surjective $(q,g)$ is also surjective ?

Comment: If $y\in Y$ then $y=q(x)$ for some $x\in X$ and then $(q,g)(i_1(x))=q(x)=y$. So if $q$ is surjective then also $(q,g)$ is surjective.

Comment: Yea, so I think the statement is correct... which I have not seen elsewhere...

Comment: Is $\oplus$ disjoint union here?

Comment: @AndresMejia, yea the coproduct in category of top spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your map $(q,g)$ is a dual to the diagonal map into products (if we have maps $f_i : X \to Y_i$ with a common domain, $\nabla_i f_i: X \to \prod_i Y_i$ defined by $\pi_i \circ \nabla_i f_i = f_i$ for all $i$ is also continuous), where here we have a common codomain $Y$ and we define $(q,g)$ by $(q,g) \circ j_X = q$ and $(q,g) \circ j_A = g$ and the universal property for sums implies that $(q,g)$ is continuous (it has the final topology wrt the embeddings $j_X: X \to X \oplus A$ and $j_A: A \to X \oplus A$).

That $(q,g)$ is quotient can also be seen by the definitions: indeed it is surjective as $q$ is (just as $\nabla_i f_i$ is injective whenever just one $f_i$ is) and if $(q,g)^{-1}[A] = q^{-1}[A] \oplus g^{-1}[A]$ is open in $X \oplus A$ this means that $q^{-1}[A]$ is open in $X$ and $g^{-1}[A]$ is open in $A$. The first part already implies that $A$ is open in $Y$ as $q$ is quotient, and we are done.